# Validating XML with XSD - Unexpected child error

Tags: xml, xsd, python-xmlschema

I'm new to XML validation and I'm having an issue I don't understand.
I'm using the Python `xmlschema` library to validate XML files against XSD files I generated using the MS xsd tool. After creating many XSD schemas that worked fine I'm having the following issue with the latest XSD

> XML file
> C:/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/XMLfiles/ADAMIntegration/google\RLS22770.manifest.xml
> not valid: failed validating <Element
> '{http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest}ServiceProvider'
> at 0x000001B4A7ADE458> with XsdGroup(model='sequence', occurs=[1, 1]):
>
> Reason: Unexpected child with tag 'app1:DisplayName' at position 1.
> Tag mstns:DisplayName expected.
>
> Schema:
>
> <xs:complexType xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
> xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
> <xs:sequence>
> <xs:element fixed="premiere" name="DisplayName" type="xs:string" msdata:Prefix="md" />
> </xs:sequence>   </xs:complexType>
>
> Instance:
>
> <manifest:ServiceProvider
> xmlns:manifest="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest"
> xmlns:md="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md">
> <md:DisplayName>premiere</md:DisplayName>   </manifest:ServiceProvider>
>
> Path: /manifest:MediaManifest/manifest:Source/manifest:ServiceProvider

How can I fix this error?

*Update:* It seems it's looking for "DisplayName" in http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest while, as far as I can tell, it is actually in http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md

XSD file #1 **episode_manifest.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="MediaManifest" targetNamespace="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest" xmlns:mstns="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest" xmlns="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:app1="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md" schemaLocation="episode_manifest_app1.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="ContainerReference" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ContainerLocation" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="containerLocation" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="type" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" fixed="common" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="MediaManifest" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Compatibility" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="SpecVersion" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" fixed="1.8" />
              <xs:element name="Profile" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" fixed="MMC-1" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Source" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ServiceProvider" msdata:Prefix="manifest" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="DisplayName" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="premiere" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Licensor" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="DisplayName" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="network" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Inventory" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Audio" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Type" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="primary" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Channels" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Encoding" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Language" />
                    <xs:element ref="ContainerReference" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="AudioTrackID" form="unqualified" type="audioTrackID" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Video" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Type" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="primary" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Encoding" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Picture" />
                    <xs:element ref="ContainerReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="VideoTrackID" form="unqualified" type="videoTrackID" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Subtitle" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Format" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Type" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="SDH" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Language" />
                    <xs:element ref="ContainerReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="SubtitleTrackID" form="unqualified" type="subtitleTrackID" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Image" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Purpose" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Width" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Height" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Encoding" />
                    <xs:element ref="app1:Language" />
                    <xs:element ref="ContainerReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="ImageID" form="unqualified" type="imageID" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Metadata" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ContainerReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="ContentID" form="unqualified" type="contentID" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Presentations" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Presentation" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TrackMetadata" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="TrackSelectionNumber" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" fixed="0" />
                          <xs:element name="VideoTrackReference" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="VideoTrackID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="videoTrackID" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="AudioTrackReference" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="AudioTrackID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="audioTrackID" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="SubtitleTrackReference" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="SubtitleTrackID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="subtitleTrackID" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="Purpose" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="WorkType" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" fixed="Episode" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="PresentationID" form="unqualified" type="presentationID" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Experiences" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Experience" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ContentID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="contentID" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                    <xs:element name="Region" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element ref="app1:country" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Audiovisual" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Type" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" fixed="Main" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                          <xs:element name="SubType" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" fixed="Episode" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                          <xs:element name="PresentationID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="presentationID" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="ContentID" form="unqualified" type="contentID" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="ExperienceID" form="unqualified" type="experienceID" />
                  <xs:attribute name="version" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" fixed="1.0" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ALIDExperienceMaps" msdata:Prefix="manifest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ALIDExperienceMap" msdata:Prefix="manifest" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ALID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ExperienceID" msdata:Prefix="manifest" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent msdata:Prefix="manifest" msdata:ColumnName="ExperienceID_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="condition" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" fixed="For-sale" />
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="containerLocation">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="file://([A-z\-.0-9]+)" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="audioTrackID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:audtrackid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode.audio.en.20" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="videoTrackID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:vidtrackid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode.video" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="subtitleTrackID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:subtrackid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode.sdh.en" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="imageID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:imageid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode.thumbnail.en" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="contentID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:cid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="presentationID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:presentationid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="experienceID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="md:experienceid:eidr-x:([A-z\-.0-9]+):episode" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD file #2 **episode_manifest_app1.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md" xmlns:mstns="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest" xmlns="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:app1="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.7/md">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest" schemaLocation="episode_manifest.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="Encoding" msdata:Prefix="md">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Codec" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="ChannelMapping" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" fixed="Lt,Rt" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Language" msdata:Prefix="md" nillable="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent msdata:Prefix="md" msdata:ColumnName="Language_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="dubbed" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" fixed="false" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Channels" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="2" />
  <xs:element name="Picture" msdata:Prefix="md">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AspectRatio" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="WidthPixels" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="HeightPixels" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Format" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="SCC" />
  <xs:element name="Purpose" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="thumbnail" />
  <xs:element name="Width" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Height" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="country" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: please also share the imported episode_manifest_app1.xsd

Comment: Added @SiebeJongebloed

Comment: And:   <xs:import namespace="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.8/manifest" schemaLocation="episode_manifest.xsd" />
?

Comment: That's the first one, I've added the names for reference

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The `md:DisplayName` element is clearly in the wrong namespace.

You haven't shown enough of your schema for us to know what namespace it's supposed to be in: we would need to see the `targetNamespace` and `elementFormDefault` attributes of the containing `xs:schema` element.

Comment: Just updated the question with the schema

Comment: You were right @michael-kay, I changed the DislplayName definition to the second XSD and left it as a reference in the first one.

XSD file #1 **episode_manifest.xsd** changed from this
`<xs:element name="DisplayName" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" fixed="premiere" />`
to this
`<xs:element ref="app1:DisplayName" />`

XSD file #2 **episode_manifest_app1.xsd** added the following
`<xs:element name="DisplayName" msdata:Prefix="md" type="xs:string" />`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay for your help. I tried to vote for this answer but I don't have enough reputation